# Condicionales con PostCSS

Tags: css3

Estoy usando PostCSS y estoy usando como en la [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-conditionals) pero lo estoy usando como dentro de una funcion en un archivo aparte llamado variables, al ejecutarlo me sale:

```
 Failed to parse expression
```

Acá lo tengo así en el css

variables.css

```
 @define-mixin backImages $x, $y, $url, $color, $size, $repeat{
   if $color != ''{
     background-color: $(color);
   }
   @else if $url != ''{
     background-image: $(url);
   }
   @else if $x != '' && $y != ''{
     background-position: $(x) $(y);
   }
   @else if $size != ''{
     background-repeat: $(repeat);
   }
   @else if $repeat != ''{
     background-size: $(size);
   }
   @else{
     background:none;
   }
 }
```

styles.css

```
body{
  @mixin backImages center, center, url(../images/juego_img/logojuego.png), '', cover, no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}
```

No se que error estoy cometiendo.

Comment: ¿Estás cargando los dos plugins `postcss-conditionals` y  `postcss-simple-vars`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El funcionamiento de los mixins son bien simples. Lo que debes hacer es cerrar los `@else` con las llaves correspondientes.

Ejemplo: https://runkit.com/jondotsoy/example-mixins-with-postcss-and-precss

```
@define-mixin backImages $x $y $url $color $size $repeat {
  @if $color != '' {
    background-color: $(color);
  }
  @else{
    @if $url != '' {
      background-image: $(url);
    }
    @else {
      @if $x != '' && $y != '' {
        background-position: $(x) $(y);
      }
      @else {
        @if $size != ''{
          background-repeat: $(repeat);
        }
        @else {
          @if $repeat != ''{
            background-size: $(size);
          }
          @else {
            background:none;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, esposible con solo if?